# How to add union data in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks in advance !!

I want to get below data in separate table with column how can we achieved this.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Based on the syntax, I left SQL Server.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Your question would also benefit from a *clear* explanation of what you want to do and sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my reading of your question, you would like the results of that SELECT statement put into a new table?

Firstly, I'm assuming your original SQL works as a SELECT statement - e.g., all those tables have the same structure. Note that you can simplify the unions, but I haven't done so here, to keep the key part of the answer (saving the data) as the main focus.

To save the data into another table, you can either create a table first and make that into an insert, or just use 'SELECT INTO' within the main SELECT.

If you are happy with the columns being automatically created, the 'SELECT INTO' version will create columns (e.g., you do not need to specify the columns in a CREATE TABLE statement). However, when you run the SELECT INTO, it does create the table. Therefore if you want to insert further values, you need to specify the column list (or have matching column lists).

`SELECT INTO` version

```
select * 

INTO #Temp   -- Added This row

from
( select * from #OneyearExpiry
  union all
  select * from #OtherYearExpiry
) A

except

select * from
( select * from #ONEYRCON
  union all
  select * from #OTHERYRCON
) B
```

`INSERT INTO` version

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (<your fields here to match the SELECT statement>)

INSERT INTO #Temp
select * from
( select * from #OneyearExpiry
  union all
  select * from #OtherYearExpiry
) A

except

select * from
( select * from #ONEYRCON
  union all
  select * from #OTHERYRCON
) B
```

Answer (score 0):

Set operators are evaluated from top to bottom so there only needs to be 1 subquery.  Something like this

```
select ab.* into #Temp
from (select * from #OneyearExpiry
      union all
      select * from #OtherYearExpiry
      except
      select * from #ONEYRCON
      except
      select * from #OTHERYRCON) ab;
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you :)